# Scala macros and Eclipse - how to get JDBC jar on classpath for macro expansion

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm experimenting with Scala macros, and I'm using Eclipse and the ScalaIDE plugin. Following [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622213/scalamacros-and-eclipse), I created a separate Eclipse project for the macros.

That worked, but then I tried to write a macro implementation that calls JDBC to help generate code.

I have the `postgresql-9.1-901.jbc4.jar` in the build path of both projects, but macro expansion gives this error:

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://...`

**Q:** How do I control the classpath used for macro expansion, and fix this?

**Update**

I've partly answered my questions... I can add `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` to the macro implementation and then everything works. But I still don't know why that is different from normal code, where I don't have to write that. Usually having the postgres jar on the classpath is enough.